# Code Behind variable is not accessible from .aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I have a variable in an aspx.cs page called VersionNumber:

```
namespace App_name
{
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public string VersionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

This variable should be accessible in the .aspx page like such, but instead there is a red squiggly line telling me it doesn't exist in this context:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="App_name.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>App Name <%=VersionNumber %></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bs/js//bootstrap-typehead.js?<%=VersionNumber %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Default.js?<%=VersionNumber %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Helper.js?<%=VersionNumber %>"></script>
```

etc.

How can I make VersionNumber accessible in the .aspx page?
thanks

Comment: Can you show the code around the public string VersionNumber?

Comment: Please show the first 8 lines of the aspx file.

Comment: Updated post with both requests

Comment: I would first add a value to the public string VersionNumber = like "2.0" just to make sure it shows. If it shows the problem is mostlukely here: System.Reflection....

Comment: Tried hardcoding a value but still the same issue, aspx page shows "VersionNumber doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: Hm. Works on my testpage even with System.Reflection. I've noticed Inherits="Solution_History.Default". Should this be like that? Or just Inherits="Default" as it shows in your cs file.

Comment: What namespace is `public partial class Default` in?

Comment: It's in the Solution_History namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution to my problem was to write the namespace as well as the class name in the Inherit part of the aspx page, like such:

```
Inherits="Solution_History.Default"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and come to the following solutions:

The cs file should be like this without a change to the aspx page:

```
namespace Solution_History
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string VersionNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Not adding the namespace to the cs file then the first line in the aspx should be:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %
```

I've tried both possibilities and both showed version numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That code appears to be exactly like the code I posted though? I couldn't spot any difference.

Comment: I haven't added it above, but I do have a namespace too

Comment: I think you need to add it in order to work, the namespace I mean. I can't see how the aspx page could access the code behind otherwise. Try copying my examples. They work on my test page like that adn should work.

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is that it was already added, I just hadn't included it above in my question. I just copy-pasted your code and I still get the same error. How strange.

Comment: Understand. I would create a new page for testing.Just the code no name spaces, etc. and see it if makes a difference. Something must be different in your pages than in mine.I do get 0.0.0.0 as the version as I just a website.